# Is it possible to have special style for special pattern in font (ttf)?

Tags: fonts, font-design

So I'm asking is it possible to have a special design for a special text pattern in a font (ttf)?

So what I mean, for example, is it possible to create a TrueType font which normally all text is serif, but when you type a string like `san` for example the style for that three letter will turn to sans-serif. And it'll only apply to `san` if it's type as `san`, case sensitive and if you miss or add any other letter all letter will turn back to serif.

Is it possible to create a font that works like this?

Comment: I'm not sure but I don't think this is possible. At least not in ttf format. But what do you need this for anyway (which application)? You could possibly achieve similar behavior in a layout program.

Comment: It seems I've completely misunderstood your question. It's not very clear, but from the comments you posted on my now deleted answer it is now clearer. You should really edit your question with those extra details.  It would seem you are trying to do something like a GREP command, which you can apply in Adobe InDesign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You an use [contextual alternates](https://ilovetypography.com/2011/04/01/engaging-contextuality/) of open type fonts to do this, and prime them to react on the word 'san'.  However this isn't  particularly useful or portable. When copied to another font it loses this feature and not all software support contextual alternates.

Comment: Is this possible in ttf fonts?

Comment: @Wolff many fonts with ttf ending are in opentype containers, actually . But no its not possible with old ttf fonts. However both features can live ins same container. so old style code just ignores the opetype features

Comment: I see. I'm just curious. But I never really liked tampering with fonts to achieve aesthetic results. Or using fonts with logos or clip-arts. To me it's simpler and safer to create solutions in the layout application instead.

Comment: @Wolff i dont disagree, but you can do this if your interested. I have fonts that turn  certain sequence of letters to logos. This can be  handy in some cases.

Comment: I can see that. Fonts like [FF Chartwell](https://www.scribbletone.com/typefaces/ff-chartwell) looks fun as well. But I'm old fashioned and wants to do everything myself :-)